# How do I get a 2D spectrograph given a data.frame?

Tags: r, fft

I have data in a file with the following format:

```
Timings  Measurements
0.12  -32.0
0.15  -5.0
0.18  7.2
(And so on, it's a tab-deliminited file)
```

As someone who is completely new to R, (Indeed, I downloaded it for the first time today), how do I display a nice spectrograph as is shown on pages such as http://www.qsl.net/d/dl4yhf///////speclab/specdisp.htm

I've tried the TSA::periodogram, and GeneCycle::periodogram, however while they seem to compute the FFT for me, and display the periodogram, I want to have a proper spectograph, as I am not yet confident with my statistics and I don't know if they are "raw" periodograms or not.

For the record, this is how I've displayed the periodogram so far:

> a = read.table("~/myfile.csv", fileEncoding="ASCII", header=TRUE)
>   TSA::periodogram(a$Measurements)

However that completely ignores a$Timings, which is another reason I'm not satisfied with the results I have.

For reference, here is the type of spectrograph I want:

[image: Spectrograph from www.qsl.net]

Comment: You might want to do some research on fft and sampling.. to get you started.

Comment: @NathanG: I could just do it in Matlab, or find another package that lets me specify a sampling window of say, 128 samples.